# Getting git pull request number from git hash?

Tags: python-3.x, git, pull-request

Is there a way to get the pull request number (example PR #1234 ) from a git hash? I'm trying to accomplish this is python.

Comment: First of all, Git and Stash are two entirely different things. Git doesn't have a REST API. Stash is a particular commercial server that supports Git, and _it_ has a Java API. Secondly, REST and Java APIs are entirely different things. REST APIs can be used with any language that supports HTTP (basically all of them). Java APIs must be used with JVM languages.

Comment: Finally, what's the input from which you want to get a pull request number? From a branch name? From a commit hash? Something else?

Comment: Sorry for being so unclear. I didn't realize that I was looking at two different things. I have access to a commit hash, and I should be getting the pull request number from the hash.

Comment: Pull requests are something managed by things like Stash themselves for managing branch merges. They aren't something that Git itself knows anything about.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this command in a [blog post](https://blog.junjizhi.com/all/technical/2020/05/24/git-command.html):

```sh
$ hub pr list -f "%I%n" -h "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
12345
```

The `"$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"` part is used to figure out the current branch name. You can replace it with your git stash.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `gh` CLI:

```
gh pr list --search $GITHUB_SHA --json number --jq '.[].number'
```